# Stop pip from failing on single package when installing with requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I am installing packages from `requirements.txt`

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The `requirements.txt` file reads:

```
Pillow
lxml
cssselect
jieba
beautifulsoup
nltk
```

`lxml` is the only package failing to install and this leads to everything failing (expected results as pointed out by larsks in the comments). However, after `lxml` fails `pip` still runs through and downloads the rest of the packages.

From what I understand the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command will fail if any of the packages listed in the `requirements.txt` fail to install.

Is there any argument I can pass when running `pip install -r requirements.txt` to tell it to install what it can and skip the packages that it cannot, or to exit as soon as it sees something fail?

Comment: Remove lxml from your requirements.txt

Comment: Thanks, that would work in this case, but in general, is there any way around this? Or is it normal just to run the command, see that it fails and then prune the package list?

Comment: If a package is listed in `requirements.txt` it is presumably *required*, so it makes sense that `pip` would fail if the package can't be installed.  If the code runs anyway without that package then it was hardly a requirement. Randomly pruning failed packages from `requirements.txt` seems like it's just going to cause problems with missing dependencies.

Comment: @larsks it can be very common to have multiple requirements.txt files for a single development environment or package. For example, there may be one full of optional tools that can be used to enhance the unit/integration test environment or performance profiling, but which are not strictly required. You still want to version control a single source file expressing these packages and any pinned versions, and rely on the same `pip install -r <some file>` workflow to standardize creation of the appropriate environment.

Comment: It's very surprising to me that 1) pip continues installing packages once it encounters a failure (download, build or otherwise) and 2) there's no inbuilt way to opt out of this behavior.

Answer (score 459, accepted):

Running each line with `pip install` may be a workaround.

```
cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install
```

Note: `-a` parameter is not available under MacOS, so old cat is more portable.

Comment: for mac: `cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install`

Comment: I had to do: `cat requirements.txt | cut -f1 -d"#" | sed '/^\s*$/d' | xargs -n 1 pip install` to remove anything in the comments and get rid of empty lines.

Comment: At least with GNU `xargs`, there's `-a` flag option, which allows `xargs` read arguments from file, so this can be done as `xargs -n 1 -a requirements.txt pip install`. Prevents [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and excessive plumbing

Comment: For windows :) `FOR /F %k in (requirements.txt) DO pip install %k`

Comment: Even without the `-a` flag, consider `< requirements.txt xargs -n 1 pip install`, or if you don't like the redirect at the front, `xargs -n 1 pip install < requirements.txt`. :-)

Comment: @wcyn, thank you very much for suggesting the windows code. I also tried FOR /F %k in (requirements.txt) DO conda install %k and it worked

Comment: To force `pip` to only use `wheels`, instead of trying to build sources, you can add the following flag: `--only-binary=:all:`

Comment: Thanks, @wcyn! To copy existing packages from one python version(e.g. python3.6) to another(e.g. python 3.7), I extended the command with `FOR /F %k in (requirements.txt) DO python3.7 -m pip install %k`. Lastly, Can anyone tell me what does /F and %k mean here? I searched "what does %k mean in regex" but only got results about "\k".

Comment: If it does not work on powershell, try using CMD

Comment: Make sure there is no comments in the requirements.txt ... It installed me a package called 'for' because there was a comment with the word "for" in it.

Comment: Note that this command is WAY slower than pip3 install -r requirements.txt. Better to clean your requirements.txt file of broken packages for faster install

Answer (score 35):

This solution handles empty lines, whitespace lines, # comment lines, whitespace-then-# comment lines in your requirements.txt.

```
cat requirements.txt | sed -e '/^\s*#.*$/d' -e '/^\s*$/d' | xargs -n 1 pip install
```

Hat tip to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23808815/215120) for the sed magic.

Comment: Works nicely. I used `pip freeze` instead of `cat requirements.txt`.

Comment: This doesn't handle comments on the same line as a requirement is declared. For that you need to add -e 's/\s*#.*$//' to the sed command.

Comment: I got the following: 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 18):

For windows users, you can use this:

```
FOR /F %k in (requirements.txt) DO ( if NOT # == %k ( pip install %k ) )
```

Logic: for every dependency in file(requirements.txt), install them and ignore those start with "#".

Answer (score 12):

For Windows:

## pip version >=18

```py
import sys
from pip._internal import main as pip_main

def install(package):
    pip_main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            install(line)
```

## pip version <18

```py
import sys
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            install(line)
```

Comment: 'main' is not a part of pip. Error.

Answer (score 5):

One line PowerShell:

`Get-Content .\requirements.txt | ForEach-Object {pip install $_}`

If you need to ignore certain lines then:

`Get-Content .\requirements.txt | ForEach-Object {if (!$_.startswith("#")){pip install $_}}`

OR

`Get-Content .\requirements.txt | ForEach-Object {if ($_ -notmatch "#"){pip install $_}}`

Answer (score 5):

Building on the answer by @MZD, here's a solution to filter out all text starting with a comment sign #

```sh
cat requirements.txt | grep -Eo '(^[^#]+)' | xargs -n 1 pip install
```

Answer (score 4):

The `xargs` solution works but can have portability issues (BSD/GNU) and/or be cumbersome if you have comments or blank lines in your requirements file.

As for the usecase where such a behavior would be required, I use for instance two separate requirement files, one which is only listing core dependencies that need to be always installed and another file with non-core dependencies that are in 90% of the cases not needed for most usecases. That would be an equivalent of the `Recommends` section of a debian package.

I use the following shell script (requires `sed`) to install *optional dependencies*:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read dependency; do
    dependency_stripped="$(echo "${dependency}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
    # Skip comments
    if [[ $dependency_stripped == \#* ]]; then
        continue
    # Skip blank lines
    elif [ -z "$dependency_stripped" ]; then
        continue
    else
        if pip install "$dependency_stripped"; then
            echo "$dependency_stripped is installed"
        else
            echo "Could not install $dependency_stripped, skipping"
        fi
    fi
done < recommends.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows using PowerShell:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content requirements.txt) {
    if(!($line.StartsWith('#'))){
        pip install $line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `pip install --dry-run`  to get a list of packages that you need to install and then keep trying it and remove the ones that don't work.

Comment: FYI only available in pip 22.2+

Answer (score 2):

## A very general solution

The following code installs all requirements for:

- multiple requirement files (`requirements1.txt`, `requirements2.txt`)
- ignores lines with comments `#`
- skips packages, which are not instalable
- runs pip install `each line` (not each word as in some other answers)

```bash
$ (cat requirements1.txt; echo ""; cat requirements2.txt) | grep "^[^#]" | xargs -L 1 pip install
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Etienne Prothon for windows cases.

But, after upgrading to pip 18, pip package don't expose main to public. So you may need to change code like this.

```
 # This code install line by line a list of pip package 
 import sys
 from pip._internal import main as pip_main

 def install(package):
    pip_main(['install', package])

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            install(line)
```

Answer (score -2):

For Windows:

```
import os
from pip.__main__ import _main as main

error_log = open('error_log.txt', 'w')

def install(package):
    try:
        main(['install'] + [str(package)])
    except Exception as e:
        error_log.write(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open('requirements1.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        install(line)
    f.close()
    error_log.close()
```

1. Create a local directory, and put your `requirements.txt` file in it.
2. Copy the code above and save it as a python file in the same directory. Remember to use `.py` extension, for instance, `install_packages.py`
3. Run this file using a cmd: `python install_packages.py`
4. All the packages mentioned will be installed in one go without stopping at all. :)

You can add other parameters in install function. Like:
 `main(['install'] + [str(package)] + ['--update'])`