# Skipping error when installing packaging using PIP

Tags: python

I run pip

```
pip install -r /requirements.txt
```

If one of my packages fails the whole things aborts and no other packages would get installed.

Is there a command that in the event of an error it will continue to install the next package?

So for my usecase: here is what I do using a fab file:

```
def _install_requirements():
    """
    Installs the required packages from the requirements.txt file using pip.
    """

    if not exists(config.SERVER_PROJECT_PATH + '/requirements.txt', use_sudo=True):
        print('Could not find requirements')
        return
    sudo('pip install -r %s/requirements.txt' % SERVER_PROJECT_PATH)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pip. It wouldn't make too much sense, now would it? I mean, what's the point of installing something if it depends on another package that didn't install correctly? Both wouldn't work anyway

Comment: For my use case it would, I install my requirements via a fab file on the server and one error stops the whole thing from continuing on.

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop with a try/except block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop pip from failing on single package when installing with requirements.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a handy python script for updating all libraries with pip ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839291/2327328)):

```
import pip
from subprocess import call

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    call("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```

In the 'for' loop you can loop over the requirements.

```
# read requirements.txt file, create list of package names
for package in requirements:
    call("pip install " + package, shell=True)
```

This won't crash if you can't install a package.

Comment: Nice solution, is the 'call' function part of fab?

Comment: also what does 'shell=True' do?

Comment: shell=True makes it platform dependent. In my case, it's required. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/2327328

Comment: 'call' is from subprocess, and independent from fabric.api. You could probably do the same with fab.