# The same list of python libraries for Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, ubuntu

I have both Windows and Ubuntu on my PC.
Usually, I work with Python on Ubuntu but, sometimes, I need to compile my scripts to Windows .exe file. For this purpose I need to have the same list of python libraries installed on Windows as on Ubuntu.

I've tried to solve this issue with

- **pip freeze > requirements.txt**
- **pip install -r requirements.txt**

but the second operation throws errors on many libraries like **apturl** and, of course, **unity-scope** like - "Could not find blah-blah-blah". For now I just install all needed libraries manually, but It's boring.

What's the best way to "sync" list of python libraries between Win and Linux?




**After some thoughts**
Ok, I have an idea and along with this another question - is it possible to ignore all "Could not find" errors and proceed to the next element in list?

Comment: Look at the `import` statements in your scripts, and install those modules on Windows. Not too difficult...

Comment: It's what I do now, but maybe there's any automated solution?)

Comment: You've mentioned libraries like `apturl` and `unity-scope`, which are, probably, Ubuntu's libraries rather than modules you installed with `pip`. If this is correct, then which modules use this libraries? Are they linux-only? And how do you install them manually, when `pip install` fails? If these dependencies are indeed so complex, why don't you consider using virtual machine?

Comment: For now I only install manually modules, which I really need (like requests, pyqt etc) not Ubuntu depended.

Answer (score 1):

Try setup one by one

Linux

```
xargs -a requirements.txt -n 1 pip install
```

Windows

```
import sys
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            install(line)
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt)

Also as mentioned already don't forget about system wide packets, pip + virtualenv in some cases play not good with it and you have to use external tools.

I think [pip accel](https://github.com/paylogic/pip-accel) will be excellent for it. It is just a pip wrapper and seems can resolve all you issues.

> In addition, since version 0.9 pip-accel contains a simple mechanism that detects missing system packages when a build fails and prompts the user whether to install the missing dependencies and retry the build.
>
> The pip-accel program is currently tested on cPython 2.6, 2.7, 3.4 and
>   3.5 and PyPy (2.7). The automated test suite regularly runs on Ubuntu Linux (Travis CI) as well as Microsoft Windows (AppVeyor). In addition
>   to these platforms pip-accel should work fine on most UNIX systems
>   (e.g. Mac OS X).

Comment: Windows cmd shell equivalent: `for /f "delims=" %a in (requirements.txt) do @pip install "%a"`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've seen this problem solved is by using a [python virtualenvironment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is pretty abrasive if you're using it on your system python installation.  A virtualenvironment is an isolated python installation, allowing you to have different python requirements across different projects, as well as being able to reliably reproduce python dependencies across different environments.  After installing virtualenv on both your Operating systems, (`apt-get install python-virtualenv` on Ubuntu, and instructions on website for Windows) the workflow will be something like the following :

1. Create a virtualenv without system packages (`virtualenv /path/to/env`)
2. Activate virtualenv (source /path/to/env/bin/activate)
3. Create a requirements.txt file with ONLY the libraries you need (Depending on how much you have in your system python installation, it will probably be easier to do this by hand)
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your spiffy new virtualenv and check that your code works. (python myscript.py)
5. Repeat 1,2 and 4 for the other OS.

As @vrs stated, it's a little odd that something in your requirements depends on `apturl` and `unity-scope` (which are linux-specific), but if your project actually only depends on python packages, then the above should work just fine provided you can get a virutalenv up and running in both environments.