# Pip Install -r requirements.txt Without Failing

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install all the dependencies from `requirements.txt` using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Often times it will stop if one of the packages is already installed or one of the packages is not found.

How can I avoid that? i.e. Ignore the package that is causing the error and move to the next one.

Also, I am creating my `requirements.txt` using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` from my `conda` virtual environment.

**requirements.txt:**

```
attrs==19.1.0
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==3.1.0
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cycler==0.10.0
DateTime==4.3
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
entrypoints==0.3
future==0.17.1
geocoder==1.38.1
geographiclib==1.49
geopy==1.19.0
idna==2.8
importlib-resources==1.0.2
ipykernel==5.1.0
ipython==7.4.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.4.2
jedi==0.13.3
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==3.0.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
kiwisolver==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.0.3
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.0.10
mkl-random==1.0.2
nbconvert==5.4.1
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==5.7.6
numpy==1.16.2
pandas==0.24.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.3.4
patsy==0.5.1
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prometheus-client==0.6.0
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
ptyprocess==0.6.0
Pygments==2.3.1
pyodbc==4.0.26
pyparsing==2.3.1
pyrsistent==0.14.11
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2018.9
pyzmq==18.0.0
qtconsole==4.4.3
ratelim==0.1.6
requests==2.21.0
scikit-learn==0.20.3
scipy==1.2.1
seaborn==0.9.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
Shapely==1.6.4.post2
six==1.12.0
statsmodels==0.9.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.4.2
timezonefinder==4.0.1
tornado==6.0.2
traitlets==4.3.2
tzwhere==3.0.3
urllib3==1.24.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
zope.interface==4.6.0
```

**Error:**

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   mkl-fft==1.0.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 33)) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for mkl-fft==1.0.10 (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 33))

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `--ignore-installed` flag https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-i
If you don't want a package to be installed, just remove it from requirements.txt. Or try this. [Stop pip from failing on single package when installing with requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt)

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. There is no mention of how to ignore if package not found. How can I do that?

Comment: That's counterintuitive. If you don't want a package to be installed, just remove it from requirements.txt. Or try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt

Comment: Thanks for this. This pretty much works. Do you want to add that link to your answer? I can then accept it.

Comment: I think this only addresses the case where the package is indeed installed, and not the case where the requirement was not found (as illustrated in the question's example)

Answer (score 1):

Install them one by one

```
cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install
```