# How to install requirements.txt and ignore not found models

Tags: python, pip, installation, requirements, requirements.txt

What should I add to `pip install -r requirements.txt` to make it ignore not found models and continue installing the rest of them without terminating?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question? I suppose models here mean the package?

Comment: Maybe this answers your Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt ?

Comment: Yes I mean packages by models @WiLL_K

Comment: Then the answer from @k88 is the one you are looking for

Comment: Thanks guys k88 Will_k