# Pip install leave if not found

Tags: python, git, pip

I am running this command:-

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

But its showing error. What I want is to not install and escape the installation of a particular module if not found and move to another.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop pip from failing on single package when installing with requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt)

Comment: @helloworld yes thanku