# How to install packages with pip and a requirements.txt file ignoring some packages

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm doing a script to automatize the downloading and the installation of a repository from GitHub. However, my environment needs some special dependencies which aren't specified in requirements.txt file. So, my goal is:

1. Download the repository with `git clone`
2. Install dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt` but
   ignoring the bad dependencies
3. Install ignored dependencies with my correct version of them (I use
   `wget file.whl` and `pip install file.whl`)

My question is, **how can I ignore the packages from the requirements.txt file with the pip install command**? I know that I can open file, comment or erase that lines and install with pip, but **I want to achieve with a full automatization task**.

Comment: if you are programmer then use `Python` to automate it. Write script which will get only good dependencies and write it in new file `.txt` - and use this new file with `pip`. You can also read every line from file and run every line separatelly with `pip install module==version` (ie. using `subprocess.run()` ). And this way you can catch errors and try to install from different place.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:
If the file.whl have the same version as your ignored packages, you can just flip 2 and 3 and it should be ok.

Solution 2:
if the file.whl have a different version than your ignored packages, you can remove them dynamically from the pip file. For example (Linux), using:

`pip install -r $(grep -v '^ *#\|^pkg1\|^pkg2' requirements.txt | grep .)`

Similar procedure can be done in powershell in windows.

Note: solution 2 code was taken directly from https://www.shellhacks.com/pip-install-requirements-exclude-specific-packages/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I execute with my package, an error is generated:  
_ERROR: Invalid requirement: '#'_  
But you gave me a idea to do it in another way which works:  
`grep -v '^ *#\|^torch' requirements.txt | grep . >> requirements2.txt`  
`pip install -r requirements2.txt --no-cache`  
So thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad that I can help. I am mostly a windows user so I use powershell (which works on windows and linux) most of the time. I just copied the command from the website :)