# How to make pip not stop installing while one of dependency packages cannot be installed however it is handled in other place?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, requirements.txt

I am trying to install the project dependencies file by this command:

> pip install -r requirements.txt

One of the packages is broken and installing process stopped by throwing this error:

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for "package_name"

However, I just install installed that package with a different name and I can use that package. How can I make the installation process not stop for this reason and install other packages and dependencies? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt) thread and neither of the answers not proper for my problem.

Comment: The accepted answer at the linked question is the only technique. In what way it doesn't help?

Answer (score -1):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt).

But here in short for linux

`cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install`

[Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69916930/19119462):

`Get-Content requirements.txt | ForEach-Object { pip install $_ }`

*Note*: You can also just use a python script for it too,

```py
import subprocess

def install(package):
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(["python", "-m", "pip", "install", package])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while installing {package}: {e}")

with open('requirements.txt', 'r') as f:
    packages = f.readlines()

for package in packages:
    install(package.strip())
```

Comment: I mentioned that link in my question and I also mentioned what is problem with those answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).