# Parsing a conf file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

Here's my config file

```
#comment 1
--longoption1

#comment 2
--longoption2

#comment 3
-s   

#comment 4
--longoption4
```

I want to write a bash script that will read this .conf file, skip comments and serialize the commandline options like so.

```
./binary --longoption1 --longoption2 -s --longoption4
```

Comment: is `--longoption3` a typo?

Comment: Ugh. Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off of [this post on sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350246/6521809), you just need to pipe the output from sed to xargs:

```
sed -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' inputFile | xargs ./binary
```

As Wiimm points out, xargs can be finicky with a lot of arguments and it might split it up across multiple calls to `binary`. It may be better off to use sed directly:

```
./binary $(sed -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' inputFile)
```

Comment: Will xargs actually serialize the lines?

Comment: @user11689504: Replace `./binary` with `echo ./binary` or only `echo` and try it.

Comment: @Cyrus exactly how I tested it ;)

Comment: It works here, but semantically the usage of xargs is wrong (or tricky), because it is possible that ./binary is called  multiple times. Better: `./binary $( sed ...)`.

Comment: Don't we need to replace newlines with spaces for it to work without `xargs`?
I am using it like this. 
`CHROMIUM_FLAGS=$(sed -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' chrome_flags.conf | xargs)`

Comment: I was initially concerned with the newlines as well, but it seemed to work fine in testing on my Mac.